# Number Out of Range Example

Tags: java, exception

I have a code that works except for the Number Out of Range Example and I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Project11
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       //declare an integer num
       int num=0;
       //Scanner object
       Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
       //do -while loop
       do          
       {
           //calling try-catch block
           try
           {
               System.out.print("Enter int in range 1..100 inclusive: ");
               //read num value from keyboard
               num=kbd.nextInt();
               //read new line and ignore
               kbd.nextLine();

               //throw user defined exception , NumberOutOfRangeException
               if(num<1 || num>100)
                   throw new NumberOutOfRangeException("Number out of range. 
Must be in 1..100 inclusive:"+num);
           }
           //thorw system defined , InputMismatchException exception
           catch (InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("Input was not an integer");
               //read new line and ignore
               kbd.nextLine();
           }
           //thorw system defined , NumberOutOfRangeException exception
           catch (NumberOutOfRangeException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
               System.exit(0);
           }
       } while(num<1 || num>100);
       System.out.format("Thank you. You entered %d\n",num );
   } //END main
} //END CLSS

public class NumberOutOfRangeException extends Exception
{
    public NumberOutOfRangeException(String msg) {
       super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: delete **kbd.nextLine();** from your code

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
kbd.nextInt();
```

And remove

```
kbd.nextLine();
```

After you call kbd.nextInt();